# Formatting USB Flash drive to NTFS

Tags: windows-7

I get this error message

> Windows was not able to complete formatting

Comment: Are you able to format the drive to FAT32 by chance?

Comment: Run the `chkdsk` command and see does it showing the partition as raw?

Comment: Are you formatting from the command line or from the GUI? What steps are you taking? How big of a flash drive is it? Are you using a special formatting tool or just a Windows tool?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you trying to format it? Are you doing it as described below?

> Depending on the type of drive it is, you can still do it directly through Windows, though you may have to fool Windows a bit. Pop into the Device Manager (Google for how in your OS), then expand the "Disk Drives". Look for your external device (flash drive, SD reader, USB hard drive, etc) and double-click it to bring up the Properties. Now click the Policies tab, and finally change the policy to "Better performance". This should allow you to format any external device as NTFS using the built in Windows format utility (GUI). Once formatted, you can change it back to "Quick removal", though make sure you don't rip out the drive when it's in use! This can cause file system corruption that usualy a checkdisk can fix, but to be safe, use the Safely Remove Hardware option.

source: http://forum.ntfs.com/discussion/1/can-i-format-a-usb-flash-disk-with-ntfs

Comment: Please credit your source.

Answer (score 0):

Try using diskpart to clean and then format it.  To open diskpart open "Run" dialogue and type

```
diskpart
```

Once diskpart is open you should find out which disk your USB is.  To do that type

```
list disk
```

then it will show you a list of the disks on your computer.  Let's say that your USB is disk 2

```
select disk 2
```

Now the disk is selected you can clean it

```
clean
```

The next step is to create a new partition

```
create partition primary
```

And finally format the disk...

```
format fs=ntfs
```

This should work and when it is formatting it will look for errors.